# Javascript find hashtags and replace based on certain condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I need your help. I have a requirement to find hashtags and replace them based on certain conditions from an array of objects.

So this is the code:

```
texts: ["Your locale is #locale. You are from #country. Other name of your country is #others.",
 "Your locale is #locale. You are from #country. Other name of your country is #misc."
];

varsToChange: [{
  locale: "Chinese",
  country: "China",
  others: {
    name: "Republic of China",
  }
},{
  locale: "Japanese",
  country: "Japan",
  misc: {
    name: "Empire of Japan",
  }
}]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
textsToChange.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, ' ' + ' '));
```

And obviously this is just changing all #hashtags occurrences. I can't figure out yet how to add the condition to match it from the vars array.

The output should be:

- Your locale is Chinese. You are from China. Other name of your country is Republic of China."
- Your locale is Japanese. You are from Japan. Other name of your country is Empire of Japan."

I'm fairly new to regex and would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to use regex?  Is this a homework assignment maybe?  I ask because this is possibly not the easiest way to do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through both arrays one-by-one, since the first text corresponds to the first `varsToChange`, and so on. So, use `.map` to transform each text into an element in a new array, and use its index parameter.

To dynamically determine what to replace a hashtag with, use a replacer function to look up the hashtag property on the current `varsToChange` object being iterated over:

```js
const texts = ["Your locale is #locale. You are from #country. Other name of your country is #others.",
 "Your locale is #locale. You are from #country. Other name of your country is #misc."
];

const varsToChange = [{
  locale: "Chinese",
  country: "China",
  others: {
    name: "Republic of China",
  }
},{
  locale: "Japanese",
  country: "Japan",
  misc: {
    name: "Empire of Japan",
  }
}]

const result = texts.map(
  (text, i) => text.replace(
    /#(\w+)/g,
    (_, tag) => typeof varsToChange[i][tag] === 'string' ? varsToChange[i][tag] : varsToChange[i][tag].name
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Whoa! This is what I need. Additionally, is there a way we can do this without the array? for example there is only one text to update and object to change?

Comment: If there's only one text and one object with replacement values, then just remove the `texts.map` part, and remove the index lookups to `varsToChange`

Comment: thanks but I tried doing that :

text.replace(
    /#(\w+)/g,
    (_, tag) => typeof varsToChange[tag] === 'string' ? varsToChange[tag] : varsToChange[tag].name))

but got an error TypeError: varsToChange[tag</a> is undefined

Comment: What exactly is the error message? `varsToChange[tag</a> is undefined` is not a standard error message. Are you sure you removed the `[i]`s, and that `varsToChange` is defined?

Comment: This is the exact error: TypeError: varsToChange[tag'>67:17] TypeError: varsToChange[tag</a> is undefined

yes, it is defined.

Comment: `varsToChange[tag</a>` is not valid JavaScript syntax, so the code shouldn't run at all if that was what was in it. Can you post the code you're using in the question?